# Django Model: Create instance from third party model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have 2 Django models as demonstrated below. What could be wrong with the implementation of `create_b()`? What would be the alternative(s)? Any other tricks are welcome. Also, this is for learning purposes. I understand there are easier ways to accomplish what I want. I'm curious to know the issue with my implementation. Any other 'hacky' implementation is most welcome.

**Edit**. There exists an instance of A. The function `create_b` returns True, but it's not creating a B instance. It's not throwing any error.

```
Class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    
    def create_b(self, some_arg):
        b_instance = B(self, some_attr=some_arg) 
        b_instance.a = self
        b.save()
        return True
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    some_attr = models.CharField(...)
```

Comment: Make sure that your instance of `A` is saved to the database, otherwise you would add a foreign key to a non-existing entry (because the `A` instance doesn't have a primary key yet).

Comment: Probably I should have clarified that. Yes, I have instance of A saved. @C14L

Comment: What's the problem that you're running into? Can you update your question with a desired end state and what you're arriving at with your implementation?